# Input box inside of a td is returning empty when inside td even with .val()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

I have `td` with a button as following. I'm trying to get the values of `td`'s using jQuery.
When the code is outside the table in the body it takes the input just fine. It is just when the code is inside the `td` I am getting an empty string.

```html
<td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDeployerCandidate" placeholder="">
   <input type="text" id="DESCRIPTION" name="Description" placeholder="" style="resize: vertical; width: 40em; height: 85px;">
   <button id="buttonTest">Insert Ticket</button>
</td>
```

```js
$(document).on("click", "#buttonTest", function () {
  var getInput = $("input[name='Description']").val();
  console.log("Input = " + getInput);
});
```

I was expecting to get a value from `I` type. At first I thought it was the input box but that was not the issue at first because the input box works just fine outside of everything in just the plain `body` tag.
I than try logging the string and it always empty inside here.

What I believe is going on is something is causing the document to not read the string so when I click the button it only returns what it sees which is empty.

Update: Thank you for the help this is what needed to be changed

```js
var getInput = $(this).closest("td").find("input[name='Description']").val();
```

Comment: Do you have more than one button and input? Your code works fine so there is something else that is different.

Comment: I put your HTML inside of a basic table and your jquery works as expected. @epascarello mentioned having more than one button/input. Do you have multiple buttons with the same ID and multiple inputs with the same ID? If so, IDs are meant to be unique and can't be duplicated.

Comment: Please provide enough code to *demonstrate* your issue (see [mcve]).  As noted above, your code, as provided, works fine.  Here's a jsfiddle showing your code (as provided) working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/92ywab7n/

Comment: The button is unique.  The input works just fine in the body tag its just when it inside a container I have its causing issues.    <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDeployerCandidate" placeholder="">
                                            <input type="text" id="DESCRIPTION" name="Description" placeholder=""
                                                style="resize: vertical; width: 40em; height: 85px;">
                                            <button id="buttonTest">Insert Ticket</button>
                                        </td>

Comment: You can test your selector using `console.log($("input[name='Description']").length) - if this is not 1, then you have multiple.  `.val()` will always read the value from the *first* input found by the selector (so maybe always reading from your first row).  Change to:  `var getInput = $(this).closest("td").find("input[name='Description']").val();`

Comment: You say when logging the string, it's always empty - this implies the button runs but gets the value from the wrong input.

Comment: OMG that work! Thank you so much!! I been working on this bug for weeks! Thank you freedomn-m!!

Comment: @genericdude76 - please note that solutions don't belong in questions. Please move your solution into a proper Answer and remove it from your question and title.